# Perform route Shutdown Logic with apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I've recently started playing with Apache Camel, and one of the things I've been having issues with is properly performing shutdown logic on selective routes. Since the shutdown logic would vary between routes, Camel's RoutePolicy made the most sense. Here's an example of why I'm trying to do.

```
public class ProcessingRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
  private ProducerTemplate prodTemplate;

  public class ProcessingRouteBuilder(ProducerTemplate aProdTemplate) {
    prodTemplate = aProdTemplate; 
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("direct://processing")
      .routePolicy(new RoutePolicySupport() {
        @Override
        public void onStop(Route route) {
          super.onStop(route);
          prodTemplate.sendBody("direct://shutdownRoute", "msg");
        }
      })
      .process(ex -> // Do stuff)

    from("direct://shutdownRoute")
      .log("Running shutdown A route body - ${body}");
  }
}
```

The shutdown is done like (http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html). The ProducerTemplate comes from the primary CamelContext (read that it is good practice to create one ProducerTemplate per context).

Running this gives me a DirectConsumerNotAvailableException, I've used seda and vm (i don't plan to interact with multiple contexts, but I gave this a shot anyways), both don't exception, but the shutdown routes are never hit. Some questions I have

1. I might be using the Producer Template wrong? It doesn't look like it's creating an exchange.
2. Can I even use the ProducerTemplate once the Shutdown hook has been initiated? I'm not sure how Camel performs the shutdown, but it makes sense that it wouldn't allow new messages to be sent, and if the shutdown route is even available at the time of sending.

One thing to note, that I'm not handling here, is ensuring that the shutdown route is performed **after** the processing route finishes processing all messages in its queue. I'm not entirely sure if the onStop() method is called after there are no more inflight messages and if not, how to enforce it?

I figure another approach is to use when/choice at the beginning of each route and send some sort of shutdown notifier or message, but this seems a little more clunkier.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

To programmatic shut down a route you can also use the [Control Bus EIP](http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html).

However the "stop" logic is not clear as you'd want to send a message to the *shutdownroute* when the *processing* route stops, but if the stop happen because you are shutting down the camel context it may be possible that the *shutdownRoute* has already been stopped.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that EIP. I'm currently looking into making a custom ShutdownStrategy, so that the Shutdown routes aren't suspended/stopped until the processing routes have finished. Will update with my findings.